# Multiple accounts, how to address correctly

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

If one notices someone with more than one account in SU, how should it be addressed?

For example:

https://superuser.com/users/282532/rajesh-kumar

https://superuser.com/users/282310/rajesh-kumar

I am not sure the best way to bring it up but here on Meta. Is there a better or more preferred way to alert an admin?

Comment: One is unregistered. He probably neglected to merge the accounts when he had the option.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - I see. So would the typical procedure be to post here then?

Comment: Well, there really isn't anything we (diamond moderators) can do about it. I don't know if the team generally cares about it. You can leave the user a comment pointing them to http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Thank you Sir. I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moderators no longer can merge profiles. And last time I pinged the CM for a merge, the reply I got was "person hasn't done anything/requested a merge, not  going to do anything".

So, just leave it as it is. Or as Oliver mentions, point them to https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts with a comment